# How to load `\data\^Ihello$` as two columns?

Tags: mysql, escaping, load

It is my `test-tab.csv` as below.

```
\data\  hello
```

Notice:there is a `\t` between  `\` and `h` in `test-tab.csv`，that is to say ,showing in vim(set list).

```
\data\^Ihello$
```

Prepare for loading data.

```
create table tab(`f1` varchar(10),`f2` varchar(10));
```

Load the data into table `tab`.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "f:/test-tab.csv"
INTO TABLE  tab
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  \W;
```

And have a look.

```
select * from tab;
+------------+------+
| f1         | f2   |
+------------+------+
| data  hello| NULL |
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

How can i load data into table `tab` as below.

```
select * from tab;
+------------+------+
| f1         | f2   |
+------------+------+
| \data\     | hello|
+------------+------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Constraint condition：keep the data format in `test-tab.csv` unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be escaping the tab.

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY ''
```

If that does not work, is there some character that is not used in the data?  Say `|`?  Then

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '|'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  "f:/test-tab.csv"
INTO TABLE  tab
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'   ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  \W;
```

1.add  `ESCAPED BY ''`
2.`LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`
The csv file was created in linux,i load it in my win-os.